# Alignning text and image on same line while maintaining text indent relative to the container size

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, font-awesome, text-alignment

I have searching through questions on stackoverflow but none of them which I tried worked. Most of them distorts what I actually want to achieve. I would like to know where I am going wrong or what I am missing.

**Some links which I tried are:**
[CSS align images and text on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596821/css-align-images-and-text-on-same-line), [Image and text on same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622844/image-and-text-on-same-line), etc.

I tried and removed them. I am showing what I achieved on my own.

**What I want to achieve?**

1) I want the text to automatically resize themselves even when container size changes.
2) When the text resizes it should maintain the indentation.
Example:
|img|--|Text line 1|
          |Text line 2|

**NOTE:** *I am using font awesome icon sets as the images.*

**UPDATE:** Paulie_D answer works but is not responsive. Check http://design.google.com/resizer/#device=handset&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhungry.pe.hu%2Fhelp&width=720

```css
#org_info_container {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  border: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #C0C0C0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #C0C0C0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #C0C0C0;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top:20px;
  width:28%;
  float:right;
} 
#org_info_details {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 14px;
}
.group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.icon {
  color: #ED734F;
  margin: 3%;
  display: inline;
}
.text {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="org_info_container">
<div id="org_info_details">

  <div class="group">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg fa-fw">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>
    </div>
    <div class="text"><a href="mailto:support@hungry.pe.hu" class="help">support@hungry.pe.hu</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;Email us</div>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg fa-fw">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>
    </div>
    <div class="text"><a href="tel:9836345939" class="help">XXXXXXXXXX</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;Call us</div>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg fa-fw">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>
    </div>
    <div class="text"><strong>505, Phulpukur Road, Chinsurah, Hooghly, 712101</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;Main Office</div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Absolute Positioning**

Position the `.icon` div absolutely inside some padding on the `.group` container.

I've restricted the body width here to show the behaviour.

```css
body {
  margin: 1em 10em;
  /* to show behaviour */
}
#org_info_details {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 14px;
}
.group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 2em;
  position: relative;
}
.icon {
  color: #ED734F;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.text {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="org_info_details">

  <div class="group">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg fa-fw">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>
    </div>
    <div class="text"><a href="mailto:support@hungry.pe.hu" class="help">support@hungry.pe.hu</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;Email us</div>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg fa-fw">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>
    </div>
    <div class="text"><a href="tel:9836345939" class="help">XXXXXXXXXX</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;Call us</div>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg fa-fw">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>
    </div>
    <div class="text"><strong>505, Phulpukur Road, Chinsurah, Hooghly, 712101</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;Main Office</div>
  </div>
```

Or **Flexbox**

```css
body {
  margin: 2em 10em;
}
#org_info_details {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 14px;
}
.group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 2em;
  display: flex;
}
.icon {
  color: #ED734F;
}
.text {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="org_info_details">

  <div class="group">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg fa-fw">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>
    </div>
    <div class="text"><a href="mailto:support@hungry.pe.hu" class="help">support@hungry.pe.hu</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;Email us</div>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg fa-fw">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>
    </div>
    <div class="text"><a href="tel:9836345939" class="help">XXXXXXXXXX</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;Call us</div>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg fa-fw">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>
    </div>
    <div class="text"><strong>505, Phulpukur Road, Chinsurah, Hooghly, 712101</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;Main Office</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: how to give equal margin on left of img and right of text?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean the images are two close to the container div border. I would like them to shift a bit more inside.

Comment: sometimes it moves out of the container while resizing the browser.

Comment: from 360px to 720px; it doesnt fit the container. Please help. see http://design.google.com/resizer/#device=handset&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhungry.pe.hu%2Fhelp&width=720